# Vertical align in tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, matrices

there is code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={draw,
      text height=#1/2+0.75ex,
      text depth=#1/2-0.75ex,
      text width=#1,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.4cm
}

\matrix[square matrix]
{
|[fill=lightgray]|+ & |[fill=lightgray]|0 & |[fill=lightgray]|1 & |[fill=lightgray]|$\ldots$ &  |[fill=lightgray]|$\alpha^{2^m-3}$ & |[fill=lightgray]|$2^m - 1$\\
|[fill=lightgray]|0 & 0 & 1 & $\ldots$ &  $2^m - 2$ & $2^m - 1$\\
|[fill=lightgray]|1 & 1 & 0 & $\ldots$ &  $2^m - 2$ + 5465 1\\
|[fill=lightgray]|$\vdots$\\
|[fill=lightgray]|$2^m - 2$\\
|[fill=lightgray]|$2^m - 1$\\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And output is:

[image: output]

Text in the right-bottom cell doesn't fit into cell. How to set vertical align of cell to center which will move this text a bit higher and it will fit into cell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use

```
minimum height=#1,
anchor=center
```

instead of

```
text height=#1/2+0.75ex,
text depth=#1/2-0.75ex
```

This will make sure the text is vertically centered.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum height=#1,
      anchor=center,
      text width=#1,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.45cm
}

\matrix[square matrix]
{
|[fill=lightgray]|+ & |[fill=lightgray]|0 & |[fill=lightgray]|1 & |[fill=lightgray]|$\ldots$ &  |[fill=lightgray]|$\alpha^{2^m-3}$ & |[fill=lightgray]|$2^m - 1$\\
|[fill=lightgray]|0 & 0 & 1 & $\ldots$ &  $2^m - 2$ & $2^m - 1$\\
|[fill=lightgray]|1 & 1 & 0 & $\ldots$ &  $2^m - 2$ + 5465 1\\
|[fill=lightgray]|$\vdots$\\
|[fill=lightgray]|$2^m - 2$\\
|[fill=lightgray]|$2^m - 1$\\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: more complex square tikz matrix]